Angular build take too much time
I am using angular 6.7. It's the finance application. there are more than 80 modules. when I take a build with the following command
node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod

It will take more than 90 mins to build.
Any way to reduce the build time?

Use these "--aot --build-optimizer --output-hashing=all" with the command. like
node --max_old_space_size=16384 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --aot --build-optimizer --output-hashing=all

